# Increasing Contrast Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image with pixel values ranging from 0 to 255 and would like to apply the following conditions to the image. If pixel value is less than X set value to 0, if pixel value is greater than X set value to 1.

I have tried to do this by using the following code, with no success.

```
for Y = 1:682
for X = 1: 511
div(X,Y) = myimage(X+1, Y+1) - myimage(X,Y)
end
end

if div(X,Y) < 100 %X being 100 in this circumstance
set(0)
if div(X,Y) > 100
set(1)
```

I keep getting errors on the "set" part of the my code, which i do not think I am using correctly but i cannot discern why from the help section. If anyone could tell me what exactly I have done incorrectly, or suggest an alternate method to accomplish my extreme contrast increase, I would very much appreciate it.

EDIT: So I just tried rerunning the program, and now no error appears but div(X,Y) is unchanged, and the set() function is not doing anything. I am getting that the final image is equal to the original one, and am unsure as to why that is.

Comment: could you paste the errors?

Comment: What do you mean by "with no success." What kind of errors did you get ?

Comment: edited it in for you guys. sorry about that

Comment: Disagree with initial upvote - this is not a particularly interesting Q, just teething problems with starting matlab for college.

Comment: regardless of how interesting the problem may be, I would really appreciate some assistance with my problem.

Comment: Sorry user that was no insult to you, I think I was being overzealous. Undid the -1.

Comment: No problem at all, I think my response was a little curt as well, apologize if my question is obvious to others, just learning to use the program as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if`s needs `end`s.

You assigned properly in the first part of your code, then moved to `set` for some reason? `set` is not used for what you are using it.

```
if div(x,Y) < 100 %X being 100 in this circumstance
myimage(x,Y)=0;
end
if div(x,Y) > 100
myimage(x,Y)=255;
end
```

I took the liberty of changing your high contrast value to 255, which sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the 255 edit, that was a mistake on my part. Your code makes sense to me, but the resulting image is still the same as the original image, I am "imshow"-ing myimage, and the image is unchanged.

Comment: Have you checked whether any of your `div` values are actually over 100?

Comment: OH. I just noticed - you are using a small 'x' for your indexing, but you have a big 'X' in your assignation/checking. Have edited to fix.

Comment: small x/big x was a mistake, but i managed to fix my own mistake, the problem was that my for loops did not extend far enough down through my code, thanks for your help sir.